# How to reject strings that are starting with some text in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to accept strings that are not starting with "::1" in /etc/hosts file using the below awk script:

```
cat /etc/hosts | awk '/~(^::1)/{print}' >> test.txt
```

But the above code accepts no strings at all.

Note: The above `cat` code is just a sample out stream. I want the awk code should only accept if the out stream to the left of `pipe |` has the specified starting text, if not then it should completely reject the out stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching syntax is:

```
 awk '!/^::1/{print $1}' /etc/hosts
```

with the pipe:

```
 cat /etc/hosts | awk '!/^::1/{print $1}'
```

Note that `/etc/hosts` (or whatever the source stream) may also contain comments (starting with `#`), which you may want to ignore:

```
cat /etc/hosts | awk '!/^::1/ && !/^#/{print $1}'
```